# Why don't we have col-xs-offset-* classes in Bootstrap-3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, offset

I read in [twitter bootstrap-3 docs](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) that it doesn't support `col-xs-offset-*` classes. This doesn't seem in line with mobile first. Is there a good reason for it? I thought they could be useful.

I read [this issue report](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9597) on github but couldn't find any sutitable justification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

3.0.1 (released 10/29 http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/10/29/bootstrap-3-0-1-released/) does have the `col-xs-offset-*` classes..

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9689