# Align two bootstrap rows vertically using offset

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I want the 2 elements in the center to be aligned.

I thought that if the first row has: `item(1 col)-item-(2 col)-item(offset 1)` and second row has: `item(offset 4)` they will be aligned but they are not.

Could this be because of margins?

How can I make `div of header.png` and `div of data.title` vertically aligned?

### The code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1 col-xl-1 profile-image-container">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{data.owner_image}}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xl-2">
        <p>@{{data.owner_nick}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xl-2 col-xs-offset-2 col-xl-offset-2 ">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/moment/header.png"/>
        <!--<div class="moment-header-image"</div>-->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-xl-4 col-xs-offset-4 col-xl-offset-4 moment-title">
        <p>{{data.title}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Edit**:
Although accepting the answer accepted, all suggestions work. profile-image-container plays with the margins and that's what is causing the problems

Comment: you can't align it vertically by keeping it in separate row class.

Comment: but it IS a different row. I thought that was the whole point of bootstrap columns. No?

Comment: My first comment should be Horizontally not vertically. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-1 col-xl-1 profile-image-container">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{data.owner_image}}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xl-2">
        <p>@{{data.owner_nick}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-xl-2">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="/img/moment/header.png"/>
        <!--<div class="moment-header-image"</div>-->
    </div>        
</div>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xl-4"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xl-4 moment-title">
            <p>{{data.title}}</p>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want data.title to be below the image.. not aside of it

Comment: I got confused. sorry. If offset is not working I think you have disabled the margin so use above way. It will fix

Comment: offset is working... profile-image-container plays with the margins to make the image round, this was the problem. Tahnks

Answer (score 0):

As specified in the link [css vertical align](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/) you can use css for vertically  aligning the div.

```
 div.class {
     position: relative;
     top: 50%;
     -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
     -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
     transform: translateY(-50%);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have slightly simplified you code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-1">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <p>Nick</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.zenimax.com/jpn/fallout3/images/avators/100x100falloutav-vb.gif" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-3">
            <p>Title</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's available on [this JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9789xtax/2/).

It seems to do exactly what you needed.

What version of bootstrap are you using? Some older versions didn't have `col-xs-offset-*` classes (as stated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19748493/why-dont-we-have-col-xs-offset-classes-in-bootstrap-3)).

Apart from that, pay attention to size of your viewport. I usually only use `col-xs-*` only.

Last, check your custom (non-bootstrap) CSS. Perhaphs the override some rules?